# Change native programming language for respective platform in VS code for Flutter

Tags: swift, intellij-idea, kotlin, visual-studio-code, flutter

How do I change the Native language to `Swift` & `Kotlin` from `Objective-C` & `Java` in `VS Code` while developing apps using `Flutter Framework`?

Previously I was using `IntelliJ IDEA` and while creating project I used to get options to select native language for both the iOS(Swift or Objective-C) & Android(Java or Kotlin) platform.

VS Code doesn't show such options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default flutter template supports writing Android code using Java, iOS code using Objective-C. To use Kotlin or Swift, use the `-i` and/or `-a` flags like so `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin helloWorld`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have installed [Dart Code](https://dartcode.org/), the plugin doesn't prompt Android & iOS project language when creating new project.

Instead you can set the default in the settings.
Search for `dart.flutterCreateAndroidLanguage` and `dart.flutterCreateIOSLanguage` in VS Code settings.

Comment: Where is the "VS Code settings."? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Default flutter create a language for android is java and for iOS is objective-c. To change, follow these steps:

1. Open vscode settings. Under *User Settings* or use ***[cmd+comma(,)]*** then click on **Extensions**.
2. Open **Dart & Flutter**
3. *Scroll down* till you see **Flutter Create Android Language** to change it to kotlin and **Flutter Create IOSLanguage** to change it to swift

[vscode user settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCSqH.png)
[flutter create language change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjcAK.png)